# Why isn't Craft displaying my plugin's changelog details?

Tags: plugin-development

I can't figure out why Craft won't display my plugin's changelog details as expandable version headers, like it does for other plugins. I assume there's something wrong with the formatting in my CHANGELOG.md file, but I can't spot it.

The below screenshot is how my CHANGELOG.md renders inside Craft's update utility – notice that the version headers aren't expandable, which means there's no way to actually read the details for each version update:

[image]

The raw CHANGELOG markdown can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft/master/CHANGELOG.md

The `changelogUrl` attribute in the plugin's [`composer.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft/master/composer.json) file is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have some en dashes `–` instead of hyphens `-` in your CHANGELOG.md version headings. These are probably causing some parsing issues.

Notice how there’s also no release date shown in the update utility.

Comment: The ever-observant @carlcs :) You might be right – I corrected the dashes to hyphens and pushed to Git; didn't help (I cleared out my /storage dir to make sure Craft didn't pull from a local cache), but the old changelog might be cached on P&T's end?

Comment: Yeah they must be caching them. So what you have to do now is to add some more awesome features to the plugin and push a new release. Pretty sure that’s a good way to make them pull your updated changelogs…

Comment: Yes, but the plugin is already *perfect*. Maybe I'll just _remove_ some features. That'll show 'em.

Comment: Or that, nobody needs perfection.

Comment: Fixed a bug, pushed a new release and Craft is displaying my changelog details now. Cheers @carlcs!